# Writing into csv file would export in excel wrong

Tags: python, export-to-csv, writetofile

i have a problem with writing into a csv file. First the "lists" in the code would return a list that has the usernames with a lot of gaps and does not show properly. Secondly once I try to write it in the csv file I would get each character of the username in a different cell in excel.

[image]

```
for i in range(0,33):
    link = (df.link.iloc[i])
    source1 = urllib.request.urlopen(link).read()
    soup1 = bs.BeautifulSoup(source1,'lxml')
    for username in soup1.find_all('div', class_="user-name"):
        lists.append(username.text)
#    for time in soup1.find_all('div',class_="thread-ago"):
example = open('generalinfo.csv','w')
wr = csv.writer(example,quoting = csv.QUOTE_ALL)        
wr.writerows(lists)    
example.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writerows()` needs a list of lists, try::

```
for username in soup1.find_all('div', class_="user-name"):
    lists.append([username.text])
```

Answer (score 0):

`wr.writerows(lists)` expects a list of lists of strings. In your snippet, it is a list of strings. Each string (being a sequence) is implicitly converted to a list of characters, and each character is written in its own cell. Here's how to fix:

```
lists.append([username.text])
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know how can I avoid having all this gaps in the lists on python?